# How is pipelining possible?

Tags: cpu

As far as I understand pipelining is a way to excecute a instruction every clock cycle. It is a process performed on single cores. My question is how does the control unit handle this, at some point the control unit will have to store results from a completed instruction while simultaneously decode or fetch a new instruction.

To my understanding a core can have a couple of ALUs but only 1 control unit.

Comment: The complexity and capabilities of a "control unit" is not something precisely defined. Even an ALU can be a much more complicated than just performing arithmetic operations on two operands: think of the evaluation of transcendental functions.

Comment: Ive read that the ALU does a lot more than arithmetic. You have comparator circuits, shifters etc. Ive seen basic design for ALUs but nothing for Control Units. Is there any textbook or source which covers basic Control Unit design

Comment: Obviously the control unit has to remember what each stage is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of CPU control is not very well explained in textbooks, and this is partly because it's highly variable, but also because it's not very interesting from a computer science point of view, as opposed to an engineering point of view. There are lots of ways to do it, such designing a control component as a state machine and using traditional sequential circuit design (or whatever Verilog outputs), to ad hoc bus arbitration, to microcode.

As ratchet freak rightly pointed out, CPU control tends to be decentralised for timing reasons if nothing else. And so, yes, even today, microcode is a common implementation technique for at least part of the control system; the overall control of a core might be RISC, but the control of some specific pipelined unit might use microcode if it's more convenient.

There is an [interesting paper on the AMD Jaguar FPU](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith21/papers/p05.pdf) which goes into a little detail as to how the control was designed. The FPU was designed as a coprocessor (which already means it doesn't share master control with the rest of the core), and uses state machines for various functional units communicating with a more central control.

For another take on CPU control, where all decisions are local, you could look at something like the [counterflow pipeline](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/974934).

Comment: This helped a lot and it gave me some material to read. Could you explain some parts of the control unit. There is obviously a decoder. But I've read about schedulars and other parts. Could I find the circuitry for them.

Comment: Lynn Conway's original paper on dynamic instruction scheduling is a good read: https://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/conway/ACS/DIS/DynInstSched-paper.html Robert Tomasulo's paper is also worth reading: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/greatworks/tomasulo.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The control unit is split between the pipeline stages.

Typical is that there is the front-end which fetches the instruction and decodes what it needs to do. This decoded instruction is sent to the scheduler which then tells the execution units what needs to happen.

The passing of information between stages itself can happen in a few ways. The most conceptually simple way is using a D-latch register, the first stage calculates its output and sets the input of a D-latch register and on the next clock cycle the output of the latch will change to what the previous stage output and keep it stable for the duration of the clock cycle even as the previous stage prepares the next cycle's output.

Answer (score 1):

A not completely outdated processor which has at least pipelining won't have a simple "control unit", but various units in different places that control things locally.

For example if you have four pipeline stages, then the second stage will decide whether it is ready to accept fresh data from stage 1; stage 1 will check whether stage 2 is ready *and* whether it has completed a task and if both is the case then push that data to stage 2. Stage 3 and 4 will do the same. So decisions are distributed.